# Xamarin - Classes not found (android support library)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, material-design, android-support-library

I'm trying to implement Material Design with backward compatibility using AppCompat.

Following the [tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/).

But I'm getting the following error

`Error 1 error: package android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager does not exist
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener
C:\Users\Italo\Documents\Xamarin\TemaMaterial\TemaMaterial\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\app\FragmentManager_OnBackStackChangedListenerImplementor.java 8 41 TemaMaterial
Error 2 error: package android.support.v4.content.Loader does not exist
android.support.v4.content.Loader.OnLoadCompleteListener
C:\Users\Italo\Documents\Xamarin\TemaMaterial\TemaMaterial\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\content\Loader_OnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor.java 8 36 TemaMaterial
Error 3 error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
public void onLoadComplete (android.support.v4.content.Loader p0, java.lang.Object p1)
C:\Users\Italo\Documents\Xamarin\TemaMaterial\TemaMaterial\obj\Debug\android\src\mono\android\support\v4\content\Loader_OnLoadCompleteListenerImplementor.java 27 56 TemaMaterial`

It says that the package does not existe, but it exists.
I still can't add images, so, here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVILw.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the problem occur because the zip file `android_m2repository_r14` is corrupted. So is necessary download manually and unzip at `%localappdata%\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4` and `%localappdata%\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` folders

I also installed Google APIs and Sources for Android SDK

Comment: You should accept this answer to close the question.

Comment: Where do we download them from??

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue to yours and resolved it by:

1. Downloading the "android_m2repository_r22.zip" at "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r22.zip"
2. Create a folder called "content" in the directory "C:\Users\Javaad\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3", yours will have a different user name.
3. Then extract the contents of that zip file into the "content" folder.
4. Clean your project
5. Build

Hope this helps.