# How to fix: expected class 'Android.Support.V4.Content.PermissionChecker' in assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a problem with `Xamarin.Essential.Geolocation.GetLocationAsync()`, I receive the follow error:

> Could not resolve type with token 010000f1 from typeref (expected
>   class 'Android.Support.V4.Content.PermissionChecker' in assembly
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null').

All the packages are up to date.

Comment: Are you using a physical Device or an Emulator? and what version of android are you debbuging with?

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921110/xamarin-classes-not-found-android-support-library

Comment: I'm using  physical device with android 5.0

Comment: try to run it on android 6.0 to see if  still have the issue